# .map no Python com a biblioteca Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I created a dictionary to map the categories using the code below, please help me. Grateful!:

```
cat_mapping ={
    "1: graduate school",
    "2: university",
    "3: high school",
    "4: others"
```

}

Then I use .map to assign the result to a new EDUCATION_CAT column:

```
df_clean_2['EDUCATION_CAT'] = df_clean_2['EDUCATION'].map(cat_mapping)
df_clean_2[['EDUCATION','EDUCATION_CAT']].head(10)
```

When running, the following error occurs:

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-122-5b4fa31846aa> in <module>
----> 1 df_clean_2['EDUCATION_CAT'] = 
df_clean_2['EDUCATION'].map(cat_mapping)
      2 # new = map(df_clean_2, lambda x:cat_mapping)    #(lambda 
x:cat_mapping)
      3 print(df_clean_2)
      4 # df_clean_2[['EDUCATION','EDUCATION_CAT']].head(10)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in map(self, arg, 
na_action)
   3968         dtype: object
   3969         """ 
-> 3970         new_values = super()._map_values(arg, na_action=na_action)
   3971         return self._constructor(new_values, 
index=self.index).__finalize__(
   3972             self, method="map"

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _map_values(self, 
mapper, na_action)
   1158 
   1159         # mapper is a function
-> 1160         new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
   1161 
   1162         return new_values

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

TypeError: 'set' object is not callable
```

Comment: `df_clean_2['EDUCATION']` is a `set`, so you can't call `.map()` on it

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found the error, created the dictionary with the content as a string:

```
cat_mapping ={
    "1: graduate school",
    "2: university",
    "3: high school",
   "4: others"

}
```

This corret is

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) says it expect a `dict` or a callable. The object `cat_mapping` is a `set` not a `dict` because you set this with the colon inside the quotation marks. Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
cat_mapping ={
    "1": "graduate school",
    "2": "university",
    "3": "high school",
    "4": "others"
}
```